# How do I locate database content from ftp?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, ftp

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone who has commented so far.  I see my post has been flagged, so in an attempt to address the moderator's requests, here is some more information:

The "specific problem or error": I cannot find the location of content in a WordPress site.  The content is *not* located in the WordPress CMS--the person who built the site created static content pages as WP templates.

The "desired behavior": I would like to be able to see and edit the content in DreamWeaver or any other program on my computer, then upload the edited content via ftp.

The relevant code (as far as I can tell) stripped of identifying info:

```
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'sitename_admin2');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'thepass');
    define('DB_NAME', 'sitename_sitename');

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $theContent = $_GET["theContent"];
```

Then a bunch of `echo` commands are used to print the values of several variables in each `theContent` row.

Hopefully this is enough to get this question reinstated.  I will try the solutions already suggested.  Thanks!

**END OF UPDATE**

I have a client who wants me to update some content on his website, and I am having trouble locating said content.  I am mostly a content/front-end person, so I really have no idea what I'm doing here.

From what I can tell, the site is using mysqli to populate the relevant pages from a database.  The problem is, I don't know how to figure out the location of the database so I can edit the content.  I can see the DB_NAME and DB_HOST definitions in the template page, but I don't know what to do with that info.

I am accessing the site via FTP in dreamweaver and should have access to anything in there.  Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: you can't edit a database via ftp. You can **NOT** simply download the db's data files, hack them up on your own machine, then re-upload them. That'll most likely corrupt the db and kill the data. It'd be the equivalent of performing open-heart surgery by ripping out the patient's heart and shipping it off to some other location for the actual surgery.

Comment: Dbs are not in the same folder as your PHP files and thus not accessible in the ftp

Comment: You can upload `phpMyAdmin` (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to access the database.  Chances are if its using a database you can edit the content via a CMS which is already present and or many hosting solutions provide `phpMyAdmin` pre-installed that you can access via their control panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a MySQL database, I'd recommend [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It sounds like what you are looking for is to be able to have a GUI to access the data, which I've found Workbench to be very helpful in non-critical situations (working in a test or development environment and just needing to fiddle with the information a little bit).

As others have mentioned, I wouldn't recommend this as a robust solution to a business-class application. But as a last resort, it might do the trick.